# What type of a connector is this?

Tags: pcb, connector, laptop

[image: connector]

What type of a connector is the white one in the middle of the photo. It has pins on both sides and connects to the underside of a laptop motherboard.

I'd like to find an extender for it so that I don't have the two circuit boards directly and I can reduce the footprint.

Comment: Dunno... but someone REALLY wanted people to know where the screws go LOL

Comment: Bigger picture would help

Comment: "FFC" or "FPC" connector.

Comment: @pjc50: No, it is definitely NOT a FFC or FPC connector. It's a direct board-to-board connector of some sort. But you could make an extender by mounting an identical pair of connectors on a custom flex circuit.

Comment: There's a logo HannStar on the board; it produces monitors for computers, appliances and automotive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mezzanine connector or board-to-board connector appears to be the term used. Thanks to Dave Tweed in the comments.

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/185/DF12_catalog-938983.pdf should work I think.

After a lot more googling, I also found a set of technical drawings that describe the use of all of the pins (not posting a direct link as I suspect that it really shouldn't be publicly available, but googling "jbtb1 connector" brings it up)

That document has the mark ACES_88079-0800A1, which lead me to this datasheet for the female connector http://www.datasheets360.com/part/detail/88079-0800a1/-5694048818178298435/

Answer (score 0):

The connector is most likely a custom job, but it looks a bit like Samtec's [Razor Beam](https://www.samtec.com/connectors/high-speed-board-to-board/mezzanine/razor-beam) series. Without knowing the pitch or physical dimensions it's difficult, if not impossible, to find the exact part (even if it is off-the-shelf).[image]

Regardless of what the actual manufacturer and model number is, this type of connector is used for high-speed connections between boards, where contact resistance and impedance are important factors in how the signal is transferred between the boards. Regular pin headers tend to have higher contact resistance and uncontrolled impedance, which can cause discontinuities in the signal paths. These types of connectors shown in your photo, as well as Samtec's Razor Beam series (among others) are generally designed with controlled impedance to minimize discontinuities and improve signal quality.

Comment: It looks nothing like that.

Comment: @Passerby I'm saying the structure and functionality is similar, not the physical connector. That's why I said "it looks a bit like", not "it looks like".

Comment: And that's also why I said without knowing the pitch or the dimensions it would be difficult to find the ACTUAL part. Did you even read my answer, or did you simply look at the picture and say "nope, that's not it"?